# Is it possible to use Google's historic imagery in Street View containers?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I'm hoping to create side by side [Google Street View containers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-embed) where one street view uses the most current imagery, which I know how to do, and the other uses [street view imagery from the past](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/4642412?hl=en).

You can see the historical imagery on google maps, but it doesn't seem you can use the Google Maps JavaScript API to create an embed.

The New York Times made something similar, but they used they're own imagery and you can't explore like in street view.

Anyone have any ideas on how to the Google Maps JavaScript API to create historical street view imagery embeds?

Thanks!

Comment: Here's the NYT link: http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2013/05/21/us/tornado-before-and-after.html